# VB script to get IP address from Ping command

Tags: vbscript, show

I'm trying to write a script to show every server ipaddress that I put into a text file. I've been looking online and came across the script below. What I need is instead of it showing 'online' I need it show show the actual IP address of each server in the text file. I've been looking for an answer to this for a while now, I've pretty new to vbs so I'm sorry if the script below is wrong or simple. This does open an excel doc which I'm pretty happy with.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
intRow = 2

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Server Name"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "IP Address"

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("MachineList.Txt")

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)
HostName = InputFile.ReadLine

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)

objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = HostName

Select Case Ping
Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "On Line"
Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "Off Line"
End Select

intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Range("A1:B1").Select
objExcel.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
objExcel.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 11
objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited because my original statement wasn't accurate. You **can** get the StdOut of a process launched with `exec` like this:

```
Option Explicit

Const HOST_FILE = "MachineList.txt"

Dim shl, exe, exl, fso, file
Dim iRow, out, host

Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

exl.Workbooks.Add
iRow = 2
exl.Cells(1,1).Value = "Server Name"
exl.Cells(1,2).Value = "IP Address"

Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(HOST_FILE)

While not file.AtEndOfStream
  host = Trim(file.ReadLine)

  exl.Cells(iRow,1).Value = host  

  Set exe = shl.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c ping -n 1 """ & host & """ | Find ""statistics for""")

  If Not exe.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
    out = exe.StdOut.ReadAll
    exl.Cells(iRow,2).Value = getIP(out)
  Else
    exl.Cells(iRow,2).Value = "Ping Failed"
  End If  

  iRow = iRow + 1
Wend

exl.Visible = True
Set exl = Nothing
Set shl = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set exe = Nothing
WScript.Quit

Function getIP(text)
  Dim s

  s = Mid(text, Len("Ping statistics for ") + 1)
  getIP = Trim(Replace(s,":",""))
End Function
```

However, the `exec` function has no `WindowStyle` option, so you'll see the command processor flash up for every time it runs `ping`.

Comment: "it has no `execute` function that lets you hook into the process' standard output". How about `WshShell.Exec(...).StdOut`? [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: I didn't realize that object existed. The downside is that to get the StdOut property you have to use `Exec` which has no options for running in the background. I'll edit this answer though because its still a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RUN method of the script shell instead and have the ping statement output to a text file.  Then read the text file once the ping statement completes and get the info that way.

```
Set objWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWSH.Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping -n 1 """ & host & """ | Find ""statistics for"" > temp.txt", 0, True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp.txt", 1)
out = Trim(objFile.ReadAll)
If out <> "" Then
    ' Read ping data
Else
    ' Ping failed to run
End If
```

Or something along those line.  That should get you on the right track.